# blank command line arguement in ocaml in string concatenation

Tags: string, command-line, ocaml

Hi I am just writing a simple program to append string to file,

```
open String
let ()=
        let oc= open_out_gen [Open_creat; Open_text; Open_append] 0o640 Sys.argv.(1) in
        output_string oc (concat Sys.argv.(2) ["\n"]);
        close_out oc;
```

Let us assume the output file is append
I ran the output just like this 
./append out "text"

Although it is creating the out file it is only printing the new line, why the Sys.argv(2) is coming out null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing String.concat in:

```
concat Sys.argv.(2) ["\n"]
```

`String.concat sep list` means that it should append all the elements of `list`, adding `sep` as a separator between them. If the list contains only one element (your case), there is no place to put the separator. You should use `^`, i.e. the addition between strings, available by default (without `open String`), `"x" ^ "y"` gives `"xy"`.

Also, you should avoid opening modules from the standard library, fully-qualified names make programs easier to read and maintain on the long-term (use `String.concat` instead of `concat`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I had a wrong conception. thought I am concatening the Sys.argv(2) with a new line character.